# Save argument ${1} passed to a shell script in a variable within shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to save `${1}` argument passed to my script (`${1}` is a file path) into a string variable within the same shell script, and then `echo` the path using `echo variable` and not `echo ${1}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply try doing this :

```
myvar="$1"
echo "$myvar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving argument to variable 'var' ::

```
local var="${1}"
```

Echo the variable ::

```
echo "${var}"
```